# How to find the third point coordinates of reflected points?

Tags: java

example questition:

> P, at a given position relative to a mid-point, Q has a corresponding
> point, P1, which is the same distance from Q but in the opposite
> direction. Given two points P and Q, output the symmetric point of
> point P about Q. find p1 coordinates.

I know the answer is :

```
public class Reflections {

    public static int[] reflectPoint(int[] p, int[] q) {
        return new int[]{ 2 * q[0] - p[0], 2 * q[1] - p[1] };
    }

}
```

but I don't know the rule using in this solution , can anyone explain it to me ?

Comment: I think this is more of a math question than a Java question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose `P = (a, b)` and `Q = (x, y)`. First, you find the vector `v` that takes you from P to Q:

`<x - a, y - b>`.

Next, you add that vector onto point Q:

`(x, y) + <x - a, y - b> = (2x - a, 2y - b)`

and that is P1. In the solution code, you can see how they have the same format of `2q[0] - p[0], 2q[1] - p[1]`. Using the same variable names: `q[0]` is x, `q[1]` is y; `p[0]` is a, `p[1]` is b.

Here is a diagram to visualize the process:
[image]

Comment: Upvoted the answer and nice illustration. How did you produce this illustration?

Comment: @c0der Thanks . I drew it in Microsoft Whiteboard with a drawing tablet that I have.

Answer (score 0):

It is using the concept of reflection. In the question, it is mentioned that Q is midpoint of P and P1.
in the answer you mentioned, P is an array of length 2 whose index 0 represents the x coordinate and index 1 represents the y coordinate.

```
Q[0] = (P[0] +P1[0])/2; -> P1[0] = 2*Q[0] - P[0]
```

// similarly for the Q[1]

Answer (score 0):

If the x-distance between `p` and `q` is X then the x-distance between `p` and `p1` is 2X.
The same applies to the y-distance. 
In other words, you get the reflected point (`p1`) by adding twice the `p` - `q` distance to `p`.
A verbose and commented version of `reflectPoint(int[] p, int[] q)` with a better choice of names makes it easier to follow:

```
/**
 * @param point the point to be reflected in {x,y} format
 * @param midPoint the middle point in {x,y} format
 * @return a point on the point-midPoint line in {x,y} format, symmetric to point around midPoint
 */
public static int[] verboseReflectPoint(int[] point, int[] midPoint) {

    //calculate the x distance and y distance from point to mid-point 
    int deltaX = midPoint[0] - point[0];
    int deltaY = midPoint[1] - point[1];
    
    //find the symmetric point coordinates by adding twice the distance to point 
    int reflectedPointX = point[0] + 2*deltaX;
    int reflectedPointY = point[1] + 2*deltaY;

    int[] reflectedPoint = {reflectedPointX, reflectedPointY};
    return reflectedPoint;
}
```

`point[0] + 2*(midPoint[0] - point[0])` is equivalent to `2*midPoint[0] -point[0]`